# redis key scheme for analytics

Tags: hash, redis, key

I want to create analytics using redis - basic counters per object, per hour/day/week/month/year and total

what redis data structure would be effective for this and how can I avoid doing many calls to redis?

would it better to have each model have this sets of keys:

hash - `model:<id>:years` => every year has a counter

hash - `model:<id>:<year>` => every month has a counter

hash - `model:<id>:<year>:<month>` => every day has a counter

hash - `model:<id>:<year>:<month>:<day>` => every hour has a counter

if this scheme is correct, how would I chart this data without doing many calls to redis? I would have to loop on all year in `model:<id>:years` and fetch the month, then loop on the month, etc? Or I just grab all fields and their values from all keys as a batch request and then process that in the server?

Answer (score 3):

It's better to use a [**zset**](http://redis.io/commands#sorted_set) for this instead of an hash. **Using `timestamp` as score you will be able to retrieve data for specific time range**

For a date range you will use `model:<id>:<year>:<month>`, for an hour range (using `model:<id>:<year>:<month>:<day>`) and so on...

Indeed, if the date range is larger than a month (e.g. from January 1st 2014 to March 20th 2014), you will have to retrieve multiple zset (`model:<id>:2014:01`, `model:<id>:2014:02` and `model:<id>:2014:03`) and merge the results.

If you really want to do a date range inside a single request, you can always store day precision data inside `model:<id>:<year>`. And if you want to handle date range over multiple years, you will just need to have a single zset e.g. `model:<id>:byDay`.

However, please note that **storing historical data will increase memory consumption over time** so you should already think about [**data retention**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_retention). With Redis you can either use `EXPIRE` on zset or do it yourself with crons.

Comment: thanks, so I use a single zset per model, and when I want to fetch the data I use ZRANGEBYSCORE where I supply the min and max as the date ranges? is there a place to see the memory consumption of zset to know how far back to keep the data?

Comment: 1/ Indeed. 2/ redis-cli info or Redsmin will help you monitor global memory usage but sadly you won't be able to visualize memory consumption per zset.

Comment: how can I increment the value of the members? since the score is the date I can't use ZINCRBY

Comment: doesn't zincrby increment the score?