# Redis ZRANGEBYSCORE returning empty set

Tags: redis

this is probably something idiotic..

doing this in redis console

```
zincrby model 1 20140101
zincrby model 1 20141010
zincrby model 1 20141010
```

why does this work

```
zrangebyscore model 00000000 99999999 withscores
1) "20140101"
2) "1"
3) "20141010"
4) "2"
```

but this doesn't

```
zrangebyscore model 20140000 20149999 withscores

#> (empty list or set)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ZRANGEBYSCORE is for score ranges lookups and you're using your members instead (in the 3rd snippet). Since 1, 2 << 20140000, 20149999 you're getting nothing back.

**EDIT after some comments back n forth**

Generally, you need to make a decision about the space/time tradeoff, i.e. more RAM and less CPU or vice versa, and that actually depends on your performance & data size requirements. Usually I'd try to use a sorted set for each model/event that being tracked per aggregation level needed. Key expiration is useful, but sometimes manually removing members from sorted sets is also needed.

IIUC, you **only** need per-model daily counters so following your initial design, my "schema" would probably be:

```
Sorted set key name pattern: <model>:daily
                               |
                               +- Member value: <day timestamp at 12AM UTC>
                               +- Member score: <count>
```

Use ZINCRBY to increment today's hits:

```
ZINCRBY <model>:daily 1 <today's timestamp at 12AM UTC>
```

Get a date's hits:

```
ZSCORE <model>:daily <date timestamp at 12AM UTC>
```

Notes:

1. You **can't** easily do date ranges with this approach as your scores keep the counts. You'll basically need to do multiple ZSCOREs (O(log(N))), looping through each date in the range.
2. You can keep additional rolling or static aggregates to speed up commonly accessed ranges.
3. You'll have to manually "expire" the older set members for housekeeping.

An alternative approach that allows ranges is to have the following in place:

```
Sorted set key name pattern: <model>:daily
                               |
                               +- Member value: <day timestamp at 12AM UTC>:<count>
                               +- Member score: 0
```

Here, you can use ZRANGEBYLEX to get a range of dates, but since the timestamp and count are concatenated you'll have to do a little processing client-side or with Lua to get the count (ZSCORE will always return 0) or to increment it (you can't use ZINCRBY anymore).

Comment: For using redis sorted set for time series data, wouldn't it be better to use (correct me if I'm wrong) the timestamp as the score? I've read everywhere that what people recommend, and to retrieve the data, to use ZRANGEBYSCORE with the time range needed. Something here is backwards for me...

Comment: Every element in a sorted set has two properties - a unique member value and a score. Timeseries usually use the score to keep the timestamp (epoch) and the member is what's being tacked (usually, the member is built out of something like <id>:<timestamp> to make it unique). What you're doing is using the timestamp as the member and the score is incremented. That means that the ZSET you're using is keeping scores (1, 2, ...) for timestamps - perhaps it would be better if you would try to explain what it is that you're trying to do :)

Comment: basically analytics per model in the app. I want to count the visits/events per model id, and be able to fetch that data per date. So, here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26174150/redis-key-scheme-for-analytics) I was recommended to use sorted sets, as also recommended in other places, but it seems that it is only useful if the counting of the current date will be using a different counter, and then daily to use ZADD with the total count as the member and the time as score. How would you recommend to implement this?

Comment: thanks! Would the sorted set method be preferred to using a hash with yearly keys and 365 values (per day), so I can HINCRBY for counters, and to fetch between ranges I can do HMGET (also O(N), but I can do it in one go with serverside generating the date range). According to http://support.redistogo.com/kb/info/memory-costs-of-redis-data-structures its about the same size (don't worry, I am with redislabs since you were garantia ;)

Comment: Not worried at all and would have helped in any case :) A hash would probably be more efficient RAM-wise, but with the sorted set when using the score for count you'll get instant top-k functionality. At the end of the day, it's all about what your trying to do...